# NSTextView, bindings and displaying an NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

My second day working with Cocoa. I've got an NSTextView set up, its attributed string is bound to an NSArrayController (I'm using Core Data):

```
controller key: selection
model key path: myString
```

I've read that an NSTextView needs an NSAttributedString, which is why it's throwing an exception when trying to set the value of the attribute.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "myString"; desired type = NSString; given type = NSConcreteAttributedString;
```

Any ideas how I can get my managedObject's NSString attribute to be shown in an NSTextView?

Comment: Can you show us how you set the value of the attribute?  Just the method which you set the value up.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer, the attribute is set:     [object setValue:@"Some text" forKey:@"title"];. Exactly the same process as the one I described in my question is working for a textField, just not a textView.

Comment: Since you’re not using attributed strings, why have you bound the text view’s Attributed String? You could’ve bound Value instead, which is a simple string. No value transformer needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a NSValueTransformer subclass to go back and forth

```
@interface XXStringTransformer: NSValueTransformer {}
@end

@implementation XXStringTransformer
+ (Class)transformedValueClass 
{   
    return [NSAttributedString class]; 
}
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation 
{ 
    return YES; 
}
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value 
{
    return (value == nil) ? nil : [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:value] autorelease];
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
    return (value == nil) ? nil : [[(NSAttributedString *)value string] copy];
}

@end
```

**Caveat Emptor** - This might be upside down and the reverser might leak. I just made it now but it should point you in the right direction. Let me know and ill correct the answer if its wrong.

You can type the class name `XXStringTransformer` into the binding panel or do it programmatically.

Comment: BRILLIANT. Not too proficient with Instruments but no leaks from what I can see.

Answer (score 17):

You can bind your NSString to NSTextView's `value` instead of `attributedString`. For this, you need to turn off "Rich Text" for NSTextView.

Comment: Yes. As it says in the docs, the value binding is only available if the text view uses a single font.